# ComboBox SelectedItem causes a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, combobox

The DataGridView shows data when the DateTimePicker and the class are used.  Adding the ComboBox's SelectedItems, I get a `NullReferenceException`.

This is the class:

[image]

```
public static bool IsMarkAttendance(string date, string className,string division, string connectionString)
{
    string sql = "SELECT Student_Table.Student_ID, Student_Name, Student_Reg, Division, Attendance_Status,Lessone1,Lessone2,Lessone3,Lessone4,Lessone5,Lessone6,Remark FROM Student_Table INNER JOIN Attendance_Table ON Student_Table.Student_ID = Attendance_Table.Student_ID INNER JOIN Class_Table ON Class_Table.Class_ID = Student_Table.Class_ID WHERE Attendance_Date = '" + date + "' AND Class_Name = '" + className + "'AND Division='" + division+"';";
    SqlConnection conn = GetConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter sdp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        sdp.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            return true;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error! \n" + ex.ToString(), "Date and Class", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Code in the event handler:

```
private void comboBoxClass_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (AttendanceUpdate.AttendanceUpdate.IsMarkAttendance(dateTimePickerDate.Text, comboBoxClass.SelectedItem.ToString(), comboBoxDivision.SelectedItem.ToString(), mainconn))
    {
       // Attendance.Attendance.DisplayAndSearchAllData("SELECT Student_Table.Student_ID, Student_Name, Student_Reg, Attendance_Table.Lesson_1, Attendance_Table.Lesson_2, Attendance_Table.Lesson_3, Attendance_Table.Lesson_4, Attendance_Table.Lesson_5, Attendance_Table.Lesson_6, Attendance_Table.Remark FROM Student_Table INNER JOIN Attendance_Table ON Student_Table.Student_ID = Attendance_Table.Student_ID INNER JOIN Class_Table ON Class_Table.Class_ID = Student_Table.Class_ID WHERE Attendance_Date = '" + dateTimePickerDate.Text + "' AND Class_Name = '" + comboBoxClass.SelectedItem.ToString() + "';", dataGridViewMarkAttendance, mainconn);
    }
    else
    {
       // Attendance.Attendance.DisplayAndSearchAllData("SELECT Student_ID, Student_Name, Student_Reg FROM Student_Table INNER JOIN Class_Table ON Class_Table.Class_ID = Student_Table.Class_ID WHERE Class_Name = '" + comboBoxClass.SelectedItem.ToString() + "';", dataGridViewMarkAttendance, mainconn);
    }
}
```

The error massage is:

[image]

I tried with SelectedItem and Text and SelectedValue but nothing helps

Comment: You should check whether the SelectedIndex is `>=0` before acting on the SelectedItem -- You have `comboBoxClass_SelectedIndexChanged_1`, which is, usually, the name assigned to an the event handler when you have subscribed to the related event more than once. Make sure you don't have more than one event handler for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event -- Since it appears the ComboBox is manually operated, you may want to subscribe to the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event instead -- You may find out that someone has something to say about the way the query is constructed

Comment: thanks a lot and i,m still waiting some one to help me

Comment: is that possible to but two event SelectedItem.ToString() in comboBoxClass_SelectedIndexChanged like  Class_Name = '" + comboBoxClass.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' AND Devision_Name = '" + comboBoxDivision.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'